# pointer array with strings using malloc and buffer in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, arrays

I am stuck in how to fill a pointer array with strings using malloc. In debug i see that when i fill the 1st pointer of array with a string, when its about to go to next pointer in the array it pass the next string in both 1st and second element... seems like when i use `ptr[i]=buff;` the ptr keeps showing in the buff array.

```
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #define size 2       //array of 2 pointers
    int main()
{
    int i;
    char *ptr[size];
    char buff[80];

    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        memset(buff, 0, sizeof(char) * 80);
        printf("Enter name:\n");fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%s",buff);

        ptr[i]=(char*)malloc(strlen(buff));
        //ptr[i]=buff;                        //that was the mistake
        strncpy(ptr[i], buff, strlen(buff));    //->correct answer!
        printf("length %d\n",strlen(buff));
    }
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        printf("prt[%d]=%s\n",i,ptr[i]);fflush(stdout);
    }
    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        free(ptr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Another weird question that i have has to do with the length of the arrays in general. When an array is declared for example `a[10]` the pointer a points to the first element of the array. What i do not understand is where the length is being stored!? is it the previous memory address of the pointer a? Is it before? Or does it have to do with the compiler only?
Thanks. i hope that wasnt too much i asked. :)

Comment: You should read up on strings in C in any good book. It can be a slightly tricky topic.

Comment: As you said, when the array is declared a[10], the pointer a points to the address of first element. But, there is no length stored anywhere. It is the programmer's task to make sure you use only 10 bytes! of the array a. More generally, for any array you use, the length of the array has to maintained by the program.

Comment: Fixed the problem with array but i am printing some junk after the original message... if anyone can see a mistake in the code plz comment. thanks

Comment: Fixed! `ptr[i]=malloc(strlen(buff)+1);
strncpy(ptr[i], buff, strlen(buff)+1);` i couldnt define end of string cause i didnt copy +1 elenete (\0). :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
ptr[i]=buff;
```

does not copy the string.  It just copies a pointer.  So not have you caused a memory leak (you have no way to access the memory you just allocated), but it messes your program up, because `ptr[i]` now points at `buff`, so every time you read a new string, it will appear to affect all elements of `ptr[]`.

Do this instead:

```
strncpy(ptr[i], buff, BUF_SIZE);
```

Note also that it's considered bad practice to use `gets`; consider what would happen if the user were to type a string with more than 9 characters.

Comment: Thanks! i used gets cause i didnt know how to use scanf() with array. Trying to figure that out now. maybe with a for loop or something

Comment: heyo there is still a problem in the code. for some reason when i print i get some junk after the original string. could that be due to bad malloc?

Answer (score 1):

The following is incorrect:

```
ptr[i]=buff
```

You should use `strcpy()` instead of the assignment.

Otherwise you assign the same pointer to all elements of `ptr`, leak the `malloc()`ed memory, and try to `free()` things you haven't `malloc()`ed.